# Instance in unhealthy status - ALB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to create alb using terraform but my instance are in unhealthy state. My application is listening on 3000 port so I am trying to reach the ec2 instance (in private subnet) on port 3000. If I install apache and create index.html and pass the path in alb health checks it become healthy. I want to make it work on port 3000

```
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = "APP-LB"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id]
  subnets            = aws_subnet.public.*.id
}
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "alb_tg" {
  name        = "ALB-TG"
  port        = 3000
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "instance"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 3
    timeout             = 5
    interval            = 20
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    port                = 3000
    path                = "/"
    matcher             = "200"
  }
}
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb_tg.arn
  }
}
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener2" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = 3000
  protocol          = "HTTP"
  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb_tg.arn
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "ec2_instance" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb_tg.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.web.id
  port             = 3000
}

resource "aws_security_group" "alb_sg" {
  name        = "alb_sg"
  description = "For internet traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    description = "incoming for ec2-instance"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "incoming for ec2-instance"
    from_port   = 3000
    to_port     = 3000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "alb_sg"
  }
}
```

ec2.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "web_sg" {
  name        = "web_sg"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    description = "MongoDB Traffic"
    from_port   = 27017
    to_port     = 27017
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "For application deployed on ec2"
    from_port   = 3000
    to_port     = 3000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "For traffic from appliaction load balancer"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    # security_groups = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id]
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "To ssh into the instancess"
    from_port       = 22
    to_port         = 22
    protocol        = "tcp"
   cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "web_sg"
  }
}
```

user-data

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo bash -
yum -y install nodejs
sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/mongod*
sudo yum clean all
echo '============================================'
echo "======> Installing Mongodb 4.0 ..."

    #yum clean all

   cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.2.repo << EOF
[mongodb-org-4.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2/mongodb-org/4.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc
EOF

sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-4.2.18 mongodb-org-server-4.2.18 mongodb-org-shell-4.2.18 mongodb-org-mongos-4.2.18 mongodb-org-tools-4.2.18
```

vpc.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = var.cidr_vpc_block

  tags = {
    Name = "RMIT Assignment 2"
  }
}
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  count             = length(var.public)
  cidr_block        = element(var.public, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zone, count.index)

  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "public_az${count.index + 1}"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  count             = length(var.private)
  cidr_block        = element(var.private, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zone, count.index)
  tags = {
    Name = "private_az${count.index + 1}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "data" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  count             = length(var.data)
  cidr_block        = element(var.data, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zone, count.index)
  tags = {
    Name = "data_az${count.index + 1}"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "IGW" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  tags = {
    Name = "IGW"
  }
}

resource "aws_default_route_table" "default" {
  default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.main.default_route_table_id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.IGW.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "default_route_table"
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "simulation_default_route" {
  route_table_id         = aws_vpc.main.default_route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.IGW.id
}
resource "aws_route_table_association" "association" {
  count          = length(var.public)
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = aws_default_route_table.default.id
}

resource "aws_eip" "nat_gw" {
  vpc = true
}


resource "aws_nat_gateway" "priv_ngw" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_gw.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public[0].id
  depends_on    = [aws_eip.nat_gw]
  tags = {
    Name = "private_ngw"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private_route" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.priv_ngw.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "priv_route"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_association" {
  count          = length(var.private)
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.private.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "db_private_association" {
  count          = length(var.data)
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.data.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private_route.id
}
```

variable.tf

```
variable "cidr_vpc_block" {
  type    = string
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "public" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["10.0.0.0/22", "10.0.4.0/22", "10.0.8.0/22"]
}

variable "private" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["10.0.12.0/22", "10.0.16.0/22", "10.0.20.0/22"]
}

variable "availability_zone" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
}
variable "data" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["10.0.24.0/22", "10.0.28.0/22", "10.0.32.0/22"]
}


variable "ami" {
  type    = string
  default = "ami-0ed9277fb7eb570c9"
}
```

Comment: What is the TF code for the instance? If you are using custom VPC, you have to provide TF code for that as well.

Comment: @Marcin I have added the TF code for vpc as well